# Which pdf elements could cause crashes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, ipad, safari

This is a very general question but it's based on a specific problem. I've created a pdf reader app for the iPad and it works fine except for certain pdf pages which always crash the app. We now found out that the very same pages cause Safari to crash as well, so as I had started to suspect the problem is somewhere in Apple's pdf rendering code.

From what I have been able to see, the crashing pages cause the rendering libraries to start allocating memory like mad until the app is killed. I have nothing else to help me pinpoint what triggers this process.

It doesn't necessarily happen with the largest documents, or the ones with the most shapes. In fact, we haven't found any parameter that helps us predict which pages will crash and which not.

Now we just discovered that running the pages through a consumer program that lets you merge docs gets rid of the problem, but I haven't been able to detect which attribute or element it is that is the key. Changing documents by hand is also not an option for us in the long run. We need to run an automated process on our server.

I'm hoping someone with deeper knowledge about the pdf file format would be able to point me in a reasonable direction to look for document features that could cause this kind of behavior. All I've found so far is something about JBIG2 images, and I don't think we have any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue encountered with two 'special' PDFs that couldn't be rendered on an iPad app or Safari for iPad. In my case, the problem was isolated to some semi-transparent gradient shades.

By the way, converting the PDF to postscript, and then back to PDF again, seems to remove the internal elements that PDFKit doesn't like. The original document was 1.9 MB in size with lots of vector shapes, after the conversion process the file reduced in size to about 600 KB, and was rendered flawlessly on iPad.

Comment: Thanks for this info. What program/library did you use to do the PS/PDF conversion? I suggested to my client to use Ghost Script do modify the files, but in the end they did their own solution.

Comment: No special open source programs/libraries. I used Adobe Distiller 6.0 as it was available at work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the PDF feature itself but the support for it which is the issue. You need to take the PDF apart and see what it contains - you can do this in Acrobat 9.0 - there is an article showing how you can use it to see inside the PDF at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/10479/Viewing-PDF-objects

We were sent some PDFs which crashed Mail on OS X and the issue turned out to be the embedded, subsetted fonts.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it's the code that parses and renders the document that crashes rather than the file itself? Yes, I am aware of that. And we have been digging around a lot in the files, trying to disable this element or that. It doesn't seem to be the fonts in our case, but I'll look into it a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been researching an issue like this as well.
I've narrowed my issue down to a single page PDF file with an embedded black and white image.
Opening the pdf in adobe reader either stand alone or in a browser always yields an 
"Insufficient data for an image" dialog along with a corrupted view after the element.

While researching the internet for some kind of remedy to this very common situation yielded up one hint as the root cause - 
from http://forums.adobe.com/message/2151474#2151474

> Also ran into the same issue this afternoon and after much experimentation discovered the root of my problem was my optimization of PDF files via Adobe Acrobat 6 with the Monochrome images being compressed using JBIG2. I removed the compression on the monchrome images only (colour images, etc still being compressed via JPEG) and now my files open just fine in reader 9.1, 8, etc.

Perhaps this is the problem you are facing?

---

Following up....
I localized the issue with 'insufficient data for image' errors to color images converted to b&W using a mac.
Using the itext & java, I came up with this solution - Detect a problem image colorspace and rewrite it. It has worked miracles. Shouldn't be hard to replicate using other lang.

```
               image = Image.getInstance( imageUrl );
            if( image.getColorspace() == 1 && image.isJpeg() ) {
                baseLog.warn( "bad image detected at " + imageUrl );
                BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(new URL( imageUrl ));
                int imageType = bufImage.getType();
                if ( imageType == 10 ) {
                           // convert the image to get rid of bad stuff inside
                    ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance( ColorSpace.CS_GRAY );
                    ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cs, null );
                    image = Image.getInstance( op.filter(bufImage, null ), null );                      
                }
            }
```

Comment: I did look into the JBIG2 thing at one point. I got the impression that most of the threads discussing that issue were pretty old. In any case, there are several elements that can cause trouble. I saw something involving "feather gradients" at one point. See this link: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2011090

Comment: Great info in the edit. This discussion is shaping up to a nice list of issues that people should be aware of and, as of now, some solutions as well!

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that Tensor shading elements will definitely crash you app. Always! It is absolutely reproducable.